# How to check if an array is increasing sequence of numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to check if an array has increasing sequences of numbers from 1 to n using a method in java and want to solve the problem using array. 
I have this code

```
public static int isIncreasingSequence(int[] a) {
        int start = 1, startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;

    if(a[0] != 1)   return 0;

    while (start < a.length) {
        for (int j = startIndex; j < endIndex; j++) {
            if(a[j] != j)   return 0;
        }

        startIndex += start;
        endIndex += startIndex;
        start++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The method should return 1 if the array is in the sequence 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on.
I can't get the desired output with my test array. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is wrong. How do you detect when a sequence ends?

Comment: I tried to update endIndex with increamenting startIndex.

Comment: But you never compare the numbers in the sequence anywhere. And what is your `for` loop doing when `endIndex` is at the initial value?

Comment: I'd also like to know how you decide that your example is a valid rising sequence. How would you detect a non "increasing sequence"? (Just by the human eye/mind . not asking for code)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS from what i understood any seqeunce of numbers that starts at `1` and increases by steps of 1 is a "valid" sequence. Everything else is not

Comment: I tried to compare each value of a (i) with i in the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you just have to be careful about where you place your increments.

Naively, you need to increment to sub-sequence each time while keeping track of the absolute index in the array. Something like:

**How does `end` keep track of the current sequence?**

Because we iterate from 1 to `end` over and over again, and increment it by 1 until we reach the end of the array. We are also incrementing the index of the array while we do this.

> At first, end = 1. So, we iterate from 1 to 1, and check each index in
>   the array making sure a[0] == 1.
>
> Next, end = 2. So, we iterate from 1 to 2, and check each index in the
>   array making sure a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2.
>
> Next, end = 3. So, we iterate from 1 to 3, and check each index in the
>   array making sure a[3] == 1, a[4] == 2, a[5] == 3.

And so on.

```
public static int isIncreasingSequence(int[] a) {

        int end = 1; // Track the end of the current sequence
        int index = 0; // Track the index of the array

        while (index < a.length) {

            // Iterate througha larger and larger subsequence
            for (int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
                if (a[index] != i) return 0;

                index++;
                if (index == a.length) break;
            }

            end++;
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah It works now but I want to know how end keeps track of the current sequence. A bit confused about It.

Comment: @sleepToken i was wrong about the approach you were using, this thing works :)